# Como incluir los registros relacionados (foreign key) de una tabla con EF Code First

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

como estan? Tengo el siguiente problema, estoy usando Entity Framework Code First y necesito que me traiga los registros relacionados por medio de las Foreign Key. Mis entidades son estas.

Reunion:

```
public class Reunion : Entity<long> {
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public List<Turno> Turnos { get; set; }
}
```

Turno:

```
public class Turno: Entity<long> {
    //[Key]
    //public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    public int numero { get; set; }
    public Int64 ReunionID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ReunionID")]
    public Reunion Reuniones { get; set; }
    public List<Remate> Remates { get; set; } 
}
```

Al hacer la migracion, efectivamente EF me crea las tablas con las relaciones entre cada una, o sea que respeta las FK que yo les puse en las clases. El problema viene cuando yo hago un get de reuniones por ejemplo, no me trae todos los turnos que tienen el ID de esa reunion, me viene nulo. Espero que me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias!

Answer (score -1):

No viene tu codigo, pero debes de generar un Include en tu consulta de EntityFramework

```
var Db = new miContext();

Db.Turno.Include("Reunion").ToList();
```

o

```
Db.Turno.Include(x=> x.Reunion).ToList();
```

Comment: Y luego como mapeo eso a un Dto?